# What are these parts called?

Tags: hardware

[image]

This is a part to a toy that as you can see is pretty well damaged. I'd like to get a replacement but I dont know what this is even called. From this picture, google lens found something called a "reversing screw" which looks similar. I also found results for "scrolling camshaft" and "worm shaft" that look kind of like this too. Its about 3 inches from end to end and has a hex channel in the center where the motor attaches.

The part is connected to an electric motor that spins it. There is a square plastic part with a hole in the middle that moves up and down on this part. This movement is via a small metal semicircular "fork" that looks like `--C` where the `C` part moves in the grooves of this piece and the `--` part is in the square plastic.

While I was inspecting the damage on this part, I managed to lose the `--C` so I need to replace that as well, but I cant find any name for it.  Since these are small mechanical parts driven by an electric motor I figured this may be the best audience to ask. Can someone put a name to the piece shown and/or the `--C` so I can try to locate replacements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The picture shows a barrel cam.

The `--C` is a cam follower.

The cam is very likely a custom part.

You could try to have the cam 3d printed.

Comment: Thanks! now that I know what its called I can find a template to start with for my 3d printer. I was able to fabricate the cam follower already from some scraps of stainless steel rod, my stick welder. and some elbow grease to file and sand it down.